# Javascript loads linkbutton.text on another page but blanks out another linkbutton.text value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2 pages.  Page1 has two imagebuttons.  We can call them ibtn1 and ibtn2 that when clicked creates a popup window (Page2), where the user can select the correct gvrow he wants placed into a linkbutton.text and hiddenfield.value on Page1.  I can click ibtn1 and select the option in the popup and it populates back to Page1 correctly.  I then click ibtn2 and it populates back to page1 correctly BUT the values that were populated on page1 from clicking ibtn1 get blanked out.

All of the other textbox values, dropdownlists, and checkboxes on page1 stay the same.  What am i missing here?  Thanks for your help ahead of time.  I have messed with the viewstate settings to no avail. but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Code for popup ibtn1 onclick c#/js;

```
    protected void iblookupvendor_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string vendor = "vw_LookupVendor";
        string redirect = string.Format("<script>window.open('/Lookup.aspx?id={0}','_blank','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=350');</script>", vendor);
        Response.Write(redirect);
    }
```

Ibtn1:

```
            <asp:ImageButton ID="iblookupvendor" runat="server" ImageUrl="\images\btn_off_lookup.gif"
                OnClick="iblookupvendor_Click" ToolTip="Change Vendor" />
```

Code for Ibtn2:

```
    protected void iblookupcustomer_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string customer = "vw_LookupCustomer";
        string redirect = string.Format("<script>window.open('/Lookup.aspx?id={0}','_blank','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=600');</script>", customer);
        Response.Write(redirect);
    }
```

Ibtn2:

```
            <asp:ImageButton ID="iblookupcustomer" runat="server" ImageUrl="\images\btn_off_lookup.gif"
                OnClick="iblookupcustomer_Click" ToolTip="Change Customer" />
```

Click event from page2 to pass back to page1 c#,js:

```
    protected void gvlookup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        acctid = gvlookup.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        acctname = gvlookup.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        if (view == "vw_LookupVendor")
        {
            string redirect = string.Format("<script>window.opener.document.getElementById('lbvendor').text = '{0}';window.opener.document.getElementById('txtfromchildvendorid').value = '{1}';</script>", acctname, acctid);
            Response.Write(redirect);
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
        }
        else 
        {
            string redirect = string.Format("<script>window.opener.document.getElementById('lbcustomer').text = '{0}';window.opener.document.getElementById('txtfromchildcustomerid').value = '{1}';</script>", acctname, acctid);
            Response.Write(redirect);
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
        }

    }
```

Linkbuttons being updated:

```
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbvendor" runat="server" OnClick="lbvendor_Click" 
                ViewStateMode="Enabled">Vendor</asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbcustomer" runat="server" OnClick="lbcustomer_Click" 
                ViewStateMode="Enabled">Customer</asp:LinkButton>
```